# Integrability of a function from Stein Shakarchi Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have a question from Stein+ Shakarchi's Real Analysis book regarding the integrability of this particular function. (pg. 63-64)

Consider the function $$f(x)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{ \mid x \mid ^{d+1} }\hspace{2mm} \text{if} \hspace{2mm} x \neq 0, \\
0 \hspace{2mm} \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

We prove that $f$ is integrable outside any ball, $ \mid x \mid \ge \epsilon$

Ok, so at the end of the proof it is concluded that such a function is integrable using this fact. The dilation-invariance property show that $$ \int_{ \mid x \mid \ge \epsilon } \frac{dx}{\mid x \mid ^{d+1} }= \frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_{\mid x \mid \ge 1} \frac{dx}{ \mid x \mid ^{d+1}}$$

I am particularly confused about why we would ever want $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ if we are trying to to show a function is integrable and therefore  has finite integral..$\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ to me means that this integral is getting very large since $\epsilon$ can get very small.

I guess the logic of this proof is not clear to me. I would think we would want to show that the integral is bounded by something finite..

Comment: $\epsilon$ is fixed. It might have been better to choose another letter, maybe $R$.

Comment: But it is converging to something non-finite. I am not sure what they did except for just ignoring where $x = 0$.

Comment: Nothing is "converging". You fix an arbitrary $R > 0$. Then $$\int_{\lvert x\rvert \geqslant R} \frac{dx}{\lvert x\rvert^{d+1}} < \infty.$$